# Creating a UITableView cell to have a dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a tableview cell to accommodate texts with varying lengths and I need each cell to have a dynamic height. I've tried using the below but no show:

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 410
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: If your text is shown in some labels then those labels must have `numberOfLines = 0` and you can set it directly in the storyboard or in the code. Another important thing is to have constraints set correctly in the cell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set automatic dimension for row height & estimated row height, ensure following steps to make, auto dimension effective for cell/row height layout. I just tested following steps and code and works fine.

- Assign and implement tableview dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

-

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) with respect to its superview/ cell container.
- *Optional*: Set minimum height for label, if you want minimum vertical area covered by label, even if there is no data.

[image]

**Note**: If you've more than one labels (UIElements) with dynamic length, which should be adjusted according to its content size: Adjust 'Content Hugging and Compression Resistance Priority` for labels which you want to expand/compress with higher priority.

Comment: Works like a charm. 

Comment: In more recent versions of the dev tools `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is `UITableView.automaticDimension`.