# How to get tableview content height if tableview is in tabview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The table view cell has a tableview inside it. This tableview has sections and rows, when user clicks on section the rows shows or collapse. but I can not get the content height of this cell.

on section's button click I am doing this:

```
self.tableViewViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude;
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.tableViewViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height    
delegate?.reloadMainTable(with: self.indexPath)
```

after setting the constraints I am reloading this cell in main tableview with the delegate but not able to get a fixed height

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48585451/4442254 You can check this link

Answer (score 0):

Try to check contentView height of UITableviewCell

For more detail of [contentView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview)